# Do I declare certain variables in the main class or in a permanent thread in Qt5.10

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, worker

My main class is my main window class in which, at the moment, almost all actions are performed and all relevant variables are being defined. In order to gain speed I want to outsource some computations in a asynchronous, permanent thread (worker class derived from QObject moved to a thread).

Some variables (e.g. QList containing OpenCV VideoCapture devices), are being used in both classes, but more heavily in the worker class.

Where do I declare these variables? In the main class and pass a reference to the worker class or other way round?

Comment: You don't. Avoid using the same memory from different threads.

Comment: Thanks so far. So if I understand correctly, the better way is not to reference the variable, but clone the object (for example in the constructor of the worker class)?

Comment: Well, if that is feasible for you, sure. I do recommend reading and practicing about multi threading before starting anything serious, though. There is a *lot* that can go wrong. And it's almost impossible to debug such stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about my english.

You can share some data between threads, but you must protect access to this data from different threads - look at [QMutex](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html), [QReadWriteLock](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qreadwritelock.html).

Bad example:

```
#include <QList>
#include <QReadWriteLock>

template< typename T >
class ThreadSafeList{
Q_DISABLE_COPY(ThreadSafeList)
public:
    ThreadSafeList():
        m_lock{},
        m_list{}
    {}
    virtual ~ThreadSafeList(){}
    const QList<T>& lockForRead() const{
        m_lock.lockForRead();
        return m_list;
    }
    QList<T>& lockForWrite(){
        m_lock.lockForWrite();
        return m_list;
    }
    //don't forget call this method after lockForRead()/lockForWrite()
    //and don't use reference to m_list after call unlock
    void unlock(){
        m_lock.unlock();
    }
private:
    mutable QReadWriteLock m_lock;
    QList<T> m_list;
};
```

Possible troubles if u try to use this class:

```
QString read(ThreadSafeList<QString>* list){
    // if list is empty, we got exception,
    // and then leave list in locked state
    // because unlock() don't called
    QString ret = list->lockForRead().first();
    list->unlock();
    return ret;
}

void write(ThreadSafeList<QString>* list, const QString& s){
    list->lockForWrite().append(s);
    //here we forget call unlock
    //and leave list in locked state
}
```

Comment: Despite it is possible, is this considered bad practice?

Comment: I am not expert, but i think it normal practice.
Look at here: [QtThreadsSync](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/threads-synchronizing.html).